# How to randomly retrieve data from the database

Tags: php

I'm trying to randomly retrieve data from the database, and so far no problem.
The problem is that the answer is given to me like this:
`{"pda": 15} {"pda": 34} {"pda": 776} {"pda": 344} {"pda": 16}`,
while I would like it to be replied like this:
`{"pda": 15,34,776,344,16}`.

Could you tell me a solution?

The code is this:

```
$stmtcarte = $connection->prepare("SELECT pda FROM giocatori WHERE categoria=? ORDER 
BY RAND() LIMIT 6");

//imposto categorie da selezionare
//imposto probabilità di scelta della categoria
$sceltacategoria = array(
'nor'        => 85,
'sop'       => 9,
'buo' => 5,
'cos' => 1,
);
$max = 0;
    
foreach ($sceltacategoria as $categoriaselezionata => $weight)
{
$max          += $weight;
$sceltacategoria[$categoriaselezionata]  = $max;
}
$random = mt_rand(1, $max);

foreach ($sceltacategoria as $categoriaselezionata => $max)
{
if ($random <= $max)
{
break;
}
}

$categoria=$categoriaselezionata;
$stmtcarte->bind_param("s",$categoria);
$stmtcarte->execute();
$risultatocarte = $stmtcarte->get_result();
//numero giocatori estratti
$numero_giocatori = $risultatocarte->num_rows;
while($rispostacarte=$risultatocarte->fetch_assoc()){
      echo json_encode($rispostacarte);
}
$stmtcarte->close();
```

Comment: Please clarify how you want the result since `{"pda": 15,34,776,344,16}` isn't valid JSON. Do you mean `{"pda": "15,34,776,344,16"}` (with the values comma separated in a single string) or `{"pda": [15,34,776,344,16]}` (with the values in an array)?

Comment: {"pda": "15,34,776,344,16"} would be the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/)

```sql
$connection->prepare("

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(concat.pda) as pda
FROM (
    SELECT pda
    FROM giocatori
    WHERE categoria=?
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 6
) concat

");
```

This requires you to first randomly order the items and limit them, and then in a separate query do the `GROUP_CONCAT`. Otherwise, like you mentioned in your comment, the `LIMIT` doesn't work as expected because only 1 row is returned.

Working demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14c35a/3

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this, but the result was not what I wanted.

The result is {"GROUP_CONCAT (pda)": "12,13,788,543,232,5665,723,363"}.

Another problem is that it selects everything it finds, whereas I only want to randomly select 6 items

Comment: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pda) AS pda ...` will give you the column name as `pda` instead of `GROUP_CONCAT(pda)`.

Comment: perfect, so it works, one last thing, since as I said with "GROUP_CONCAT" it selects all the rows it finds, I would like to know if there is a way to limit the results.